# Como registra todas classes de validação com DryIoc?

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, dryioc

Como posso registra todas as minhas classes de validação usando DryIoc de forma dinâmica ?

Estou tentando da seguinte forma a baixo;

```
using DryIoc;
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TesteDryIoC.IU
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Type[] GetTypesInNamespace()
        {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "TesteDryIoC.IU.Validator", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var container = new Container();

            var implementingClasses =
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() 
                .GetTypes().Where(type => String.Equals(type.Namespace, "TesteDryIoC.IU.Validator", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                     type.Name.EndsWith("Validator"));  

            foreach (var implementingClass in implementingClasses)
            {
                    container.Register(implementingClass, Reuse.Singleton);
            }

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            var validador = new ProvaderValidator<Cliente>().GetValidator(container);

            cliente.Nome = "";
            cliente.SobreNome = "Souza";
            cliente.Observacao = "teste";
            cliente.Email = "marconcili@hotmail.com";
            cliente.Idade = 32;
            cliente.DtInclusao = DateTime.Now;
            cliente.Ativo = true;
            cliente.Senha = "";

            var resultad0 = validador.Validate(cliente);

            foreach (var item in resultad0.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ErrorMessage);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Minhas classes de validação sempre terminam com **Validator** como mostrado a baixo.

```
using FluentValidation;

namespace TesteDryIoC.IU.Validator
{
    class ProdutoValidator : AbstractValidator<Produto>
    {
        public ProdutoValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Nome)
               // Garante que a propriedade especificada não seja nula                            
               .NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} deve ser preenchido");
        }
    }
}
```

Classe produto;

```
namespace TesteDryIoC.IU
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe genérica para fazer o registro.

```
using DryIoc;
using FluentValidation;

namespace TesteDryIoC.IU
{
    public class ProvaderValidator<T> where T : class 
    {
        public IValidator GetValidator(Container container)
        {

            var validador = container.Resolve<IValidator<T>>();
            return validador;
        }
    }
}
```

O Problema aqui é que quando entra na linha `var validador = container.Resolve<IValidator<T>>();` ele retorna o seguinte erro;

> DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve IValidator
>   Where no service registrations found  and no dynamic registrations
>   found in 0 Rules.DynamicServiceProviders and nothing in 0
>   Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'

O erro com mais detalhes;

> DryIoc.ContainerException occurred   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=Unable to resolve IValidator Where no service
>   registrations found   and no dynamic registrations found in 0
>   Rules.DynamicServiceProviders   and nothing in 0
>   Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers   Source=TesteDryIoC.IU   StackTrace:
>   at DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2,
>   Object arg3) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   11242    at DryIoc.Container.ThrowUnableToResolve(Request request) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   893    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory(Request
>   request) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   851    at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultDelegate(Type
>   serviceType, Boolean ifUnresolvedReturnDefault) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   557    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType,
>   Boolean ifUnresolvedReturnDefault) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   475    at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve[TService](IResolver resolver,
>   IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\DryIoc\Container.cs:line
>   5665    at TesteDryIoC.IU.ProvaderValidator`1.GetValidator(Container
>   container) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\IProvaderValidator.cs:line
>   11    at TesteDryIoC.IU.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Work\SolutionTest\TesteDryIoC\TesteDryIoC.IU\Program.cs:line 31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foi meio complicado resolver esse problema, demorei bastante, mas aí está a solução que encontrei. Primeiro, criamos um método assim:

```
public static void RegisterGeneric<T>(Container container, IValidator<T> validator, IReuse reuse)
{
    container.RegisterDelegate(typeof(IValidator<T>), r => validator, reuse);
}
```

Depois de descobrir todos os seus *Validators*, dentro do `foreach` você usa **reflection** para instanciar a classe em questão e chame esse novo método:

```
foreach (var implementingClass in implementingClasses)
{
    dynamic validator = Activator.CreateInstance(implementingClass);
    RegisterGeneric(container, validator, Reuse.Singleton);
}
```

---

### Observações

Como precisamos passar um objeto do tipo `IValidator<T>` que é genérico, não podemos fazer isso:

```
var validator = (IValidator<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(implementingClass);
```

e nem isso:

```
IValidator<T> validator = Activator.CreateInstance(implementingClass);
```

e se usarmos `object`, o código não compila porque não dá para passar um `object` como argumento em um método que espera um tipo genérico (nesse caso, `IValidator<>`). Por isso foi necessário "abusar" do `dynamic`.

Eu não costumo utilizar muito o `dynamic`, achei aceitável nesse caso pois você já garantiu que todos os tipos encontrados serão implementações da interface `IValidator<>`.

Comment: Vlw, legal que conseguiu acha uma solução, se tratando de dryioc é uma coisa pouco inexplorada ainda, eu achei uma forma de fazer isso um pouco um pouco diferente. Caso não apareça algo melhor sinalizo sua resposta no final da recompensa.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza obrigado! Eu mesmo não conhecia, instalei aqui para fazer os testes, mas essa questão de registrar várias classes de uma determinada interface dinamicamente é algo que sempre acabamos precisando usar em frameworks de injeção de dependência. Vou continuar pensando aqui e qualquer coisa eu edito minha resposta com uma segunda alternativa.

Comment: postei a forma como fiz.

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei uma forma diferente de fazer a injeção de dependência, estava pecando no meu foreach.

```
foreach (var implementingClass in implementingClasses)
{
        container.Register(implementingClass, Reuse.Singleton);
}
```

Foi necessário recuperar a interface (interfaceValidator) no loop e fazer a injeção usando ela.

```
public static class ContainerRegister
{
    public static Container getContainer()
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        var implementingClasses =
           Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
           .GetTypes().Where(type =>
           type.ImplementsServiceType(typeof(IValidator))
           );

        foreach (var implementingClass in implementingClasses)
        {
            var interfaceValidator = implementingClass.GetImplementedInterfaces()[0];
            container.Register(interfaceValidator, implementingClass);
        }

        return container;
    }
}
```

Como eu podia ter mais de uma classe com validação precisei alterar a forma como recuperar a classe correta.

```
public static class ProvadersValidator<T1> where T1 : class
{
    public static IValidator GetValidators(Container container, Func<IEnumerable<IValidator<T1>>, IValidator<T1>> criterio = null)
    {
        var validador = container.Resolve<Lazy<IEnumerable<IValidator<T1>>>>();
        var validadores = validador.Value;
        // TODO: função para selecionar qual usar
        if (criterio != null)
            return criterio(validadores);

        return validadores.First();
    }
}
```

Minha chamada ficou assim.

```
var container = ContainerRegister.getContainer();
//
var validadorDefout = ProvadersValidator<Produto>.GetValidators(container);

// buscar a validador especifico por propriedade
var validadorPropriedade = ProvadersValidator<Cliente>.GetValidators(container, (validadores) =>
{
    var validadorEncontrado = validadores.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CreateDescriptor().GetRulesForMember("Observacao").Any());
    return validadorEncontrado ?? validadores.First();
});
```